# make 2 rows with 3 blocks on a row - responsive (only html and css without bootstrap)

Tags: html, css

Hei!
I want to make the next responsive layer, with **no** bootstrap or other framework ..... I want to start it from zero.

[image]

I'd like to have responsive blocks and when I resize the page I'd like them to be displayed in one column and I'd like to have a fixed but responsive menu too.

I have my navbar and my menu, but I have problems organising the blocks.

This is what I have so far:

**html**

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="navbar">
        ...
    </div><!-- navbar -->
      
    <div class="menu-left" id="menu-left">
        ...
    </div><!-- menu left -->

<div class="blocks">

    <div class="column-one">
        <div class="column-one-first-block"></div>
        <div class="column-one-second-block"></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="column-two">
        <div class="column-two-first-block"></div>
        <div class="column-two-second-block"></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="column-three">
        <div class="column-three-first-block"></div>
        <div class="column-three-second-block"></div>
    </div>

</div>


</div><!-- container -->
```

**css**

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #EAEAEA;
}

.navbar{
    background-color: #009EE0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 54px;
}
    
#menu-left{
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 230px;
    background-color: #FFF;
}
```

And for the blocks I don't have something relevant ....

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Media (max-width: /the width under this make block one column/)`

```
    <div class="blocks-container">

        <div class="blocks"></div>
        <div class="blocks"></div>
        <div class="blocks"></div>
        <div class="blocks"></div>
        <div class="blocks"></div>
        <div class="blocks"></div>

    </div>
```

css

```
.blocks-container {
    width: calc(100% - 230px);
    height: calc(100% - 54px);
    position: absolute;
    top: 54px;
    left: 230px;
}

.blocks {
    width: 33%;
    height: 50%;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    float: left;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .blocks {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```